# After enabling apparmor Lightdm does not login automatically

Tags: linux, debian, lightdm, apparmor

I am trying to enable apparmor for Linux system (Debian 8). After Enabling i notice that my lightdm does not start. If i enable complain mode in apparmor for lightdm. it works . Posting logs for both complain and enforce mode. Need some guidance in addressing this.

Complain mode:

```
    2016 Aug 16 14:51:49::kernel::[ 5350.027714] audit_printk_skb: 39 callbacks suppressed
    2016 Aug 16 14:51:49::kernel::[ 5350.034198] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339309.078:333): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr                      /sbin/lightdm" pid=1471 comm="apparmor_parser"
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:40::kernel::[ 5401.555992] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339360.606:334): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/bin/systemctl" name="/proc/cmdline" pid=1486 comm="systemctl" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:40::kernel::[ 5401.576597] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339360.630:335): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1486 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDF2
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:40::kernel::[ 5401.596662] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339360.650:336): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1486 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDED
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:40::kernel::[ 5401.616659] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339360.670:337): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1486 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDDE
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:44::kernel::[ 5405.450712] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339364.502:338): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/bin/systemctl" name="/proc/cmdline" pid=1493 comm="systemctl" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:44::kernel::[ 5405.474830] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339364.530:339): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1493 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDEE
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:44::kernel::[ 5405.498664] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339364.554:340): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1493 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDEB
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:44::kernel::[ 5405.518628] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339364.570:341): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1493 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDEB
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:44::kernel::[ 5405.803493] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339364.854:342): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/bin/systemctl" pid=1493 comm="systemctl" target=E06783DDE06783DD083683DD083683DD103683DD103683DDE0
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::systemd[1]:: Starting Light Display Manager...
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::lightdm[1511]:: ** (lightdm:1511): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::systemd[1]:: Started Light Display Manager.
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::kernel::[ 5406.626506] audit_printk_skb: 675 callbacks suppressed
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::kernel::[ 5406.632966] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339365.678:570): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm//null-1//null-2" name="/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/" pid=1517 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    2016 Aug 16 14:52:45::kernel::[ 5406.653291] audit: type=1400 audit(1471339365.706:571): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm//null-1//null-2" name="/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf" pid=1517 comm="Xorg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Enforce Mode:

```
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.842180] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.845801] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.849171] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.875204] FS-Cache: Loaded
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.909469] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   17.973244] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.462411] audit_printk_skb: 132 callbacks suppressed
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.466439] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.516:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/run/lightdm.pid" pid=850 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.479936] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.532:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/" pid=850 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.491167] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.548:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf" pid=850 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.811321] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.864:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/run/lightdm.pid" pid=856 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.829537] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.884:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/" pid=856 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   21.846933] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346129.900:61): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf" pid=856 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.064998] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346130.120:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/run/lightdm.pid" pid=867 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.086006] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346130.140:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/" pid=867 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.102925] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346130.156:64): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf" pid=867 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.312828] audit: type=1400 audit(1471346130.368:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/lightdm" name="/run/lightdm.pid" pid=880 comm="lightdm" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.612053] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.749550] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.754211] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.754340] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.767885] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.772553] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.777343] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.781936] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.791062] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.800174] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.804856] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:30::kernel::[   22.809519] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
2016 Aug 16 16:45:31::kernel::[   23.171862] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth2: link down
2016 Aug 16 16:45:31::kernel::[   23.171885] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth2: link down
2016 Aug 16 16:45:31::kernel::[   23.172151] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
2016 Aug 16 16:45:32::kernel::[   24.850823] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth2: link up
2016 Aug 16 16:45:32::kernel::[   24.851054] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
```

**Job for lightdm.service failed. See 'systemctl status lightdm.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.**

```
user:~# systemctl status lightdm.service
Failed to read /proc/cmdline. Ignoring: Permission denied
â lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2016-08-16 17:06:26 IST; 5s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 1262 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1259 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1262 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Failed to get boot id: Permission denied
```